# How to establish an internet link between an android phone and laptop using Java

Tags: android

I am developing a team viewer kind of application to access remote computer using android phone for academic purpose.  How can one establish a connection between the phone and PC using the Internet specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html).
But why are you developing something for which a [really good solution](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.logmein.joinme) already exists?